# Looking for script that zoom in less on selected object

Tags: objects, 3d-view, camera

I am looking for a script that zoom in a little less on the selected object. I always end up zooming out again because in order to be able to select all vertecies, see attachment.

[image]

Comment: May I ask why do you need a script? Are the bulit in tools (Zoom border or Ctrl+MouseWheelButton and dragging) not able achieve te levol of zoom wanted? Or you need some way to zoom onto the selected object automatically (like Local view does)?

Comment: Carlo, I use Zoom Selected on my custom made pie menu all the time,but i always end up having to scroll out from the selected object all the time which is really frustrating. It may not sound like a big deal but it's very frustrating with all that extra hand movement over 10 hours of work.

Comment: m.ardito, I have not made a custom command, i have made a custom menu. The command i am using is they default Blender command (NUM.)

Comment: Yes, I see, deleted comment above, after I realized that that zoom is really exagerated, but that is also the standard beahaviour... weird. changing view clip start does something (changing it from the default 0.1 to some 4.0) but also such a high clip start is not good zooming near the object of course...

Comment: I got offered sort of a sollution in an other tread, Maybe someone can improve this script? http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?386503-Blenders-default-command-for-zoom-selected